# Infix to Postfix notation not respecting second set of parentheses

Tags: c++, loops, if-statement, postfix-notation

Having trouble getting the correct outcome of 
Infix: (A+B)/(C-D) Postfix: AB+CD-/

I keep getting Postfix: AB+C/D-

I do know that the issue is coming from it not being able to pop the last operators from the stack before pushing '(' This is why I added the if statement in the first else if condition. That also doesn't work. What is it exactly that I am doing wrong? Is there another way into tackling this problem?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int precedence(char x) {
    int op;
    if (x == '(' || x==')')
        op = 1;
    else if (x == '^')
        op = 2;
    else  if (x == '*')
        op = 3;
    else  if ( x == '/')
        op = 4;
    else  if (x == '+')
        op = 5;
    else  if (x == '-')
        op = 6;
    return op;
}

int main() 
{
    string getInfix;
    cout << "Infix: ";
    getline(cin, getInfix);
    stack<char> opStack;
    stringstream showInfix;


    for (unsigned i = 0; i < getInfix.length(); i++) 
    {
        if (getInfix[i] == '+' || getInfix[i] == '-' || getInfix[i] == '*' || getInfix[i] == '/'  || getInfix[i] == '^') 
        {
            while (!opStack.empty() && precedence(opStack.top() <= precedence(getInfix[i])) 
            {
                showInfix << opStack.top();
                opStack.pop();
            }
            opStack.push(getInfix[i]);
        }
        else if (getInfix[i] == '(') 
        {
            opStack.push(getInfix[i]);
            opStack.pop();

            if (getInfix[i]=='(' && !opStack.empty()) 
            {
                opStack.push(getInfix[i]);
                opStack.pop();
            }
        }        
        else if (getInfix [i]==')') 
        {                   
          showInfix << opStack.top();
          opStack.pop();
        }
        else 
        {
            showInfix << getInfix[i];
        }
    }

    while (!opStack.empty()) 
    {
        showInfix << opStack.top();
        opStack.pop();
    }

    cout << "Postfix: "<<""<<showInfix.str() << endl;

    cin.ignore ( numeric_limits< streamsize >:: max(),'\n');
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Really would help to indent the code so that's it's legible

Comment: Why are you doing opStack.push and then immediately opStack.pop? What is the purpose of this?

Comment: Why does the right paren have the same precedence as the left paren?  The classical way to do this is that the left paren has the highest precedence than any of the operators (thus will always be pushed onto the stack).  The right paren has the lowest precedence than any operators, but doesn't get pushed onto the stack -- it is used just as a "pop starter" until the left paren is encountered.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't set `op`

```
const int precedence(const char x) noexcept(true) {
  switch (x) {
    case '(': case ')':
      return 1;
    case '^':
      return 2;
    case '*':
      return 3;
    case '/':
      return 4;
    case '+':
      return 5;
    case '-':
      return 6;
  }  
  return -1;
}
```

It returns -1 but I'll let you figure that part out. 
It doesn't answer the question. 
I just stopped after I saw you could be reading garbage values.

Comment: You are right, it is not set. But if you read the rest of the code, you'll see that this method is only called for `'+' ,'-' ,'*','/'`or ` '^'` characters... So this is not the problem ...

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from this line `(!opStack.empty() && precedence(opStack.top() <=precedence(getInfix[i]))`

You are popping the last operator you found without checking if you are in a parenthesis statement or not. You need to take parentheses characters into account before adding an operator to the output string.

Not related to your problem but some advices :

- indent your code, simplifies visibility and trust me, saves you (and us) time.
- Do not `push` and then `pop` for `(`or `)` characters, this is just like ignoring them.
- You are missing a `)` on this line I imagine it's a copy/paste problem : `while (!opStack.empty() && precedence(opStack.top() <=precedence(getInfix[i]))`
- You do realize you test precedence for `(` and `)` but you are never actually calling that method with that type of character?